# can't find a vector in managed_shared_memory(boost;c++)

Tags: c++, boost

I using example from boost documenation but, it doesn't work =(
this is server app and in this case all right

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::interprocess;

typedef allocator<int,managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>  ShmemAllocator;
typedef vector<int, ShmemAllocator> MyVector;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
      struct shm_remove
      {
         shm_remove() { shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
         ~shm_remove(){ shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
      } remover;

   managed_shared_memory segment(create_only, "MySharedMemory", 65536);
   const ShmemAllocator alloc_inst (segment.get_segment_manager());
   MyVector *myvector = segment.construct<MyVector>("MyVector")(alloc_inst);
   for (int i=0;i<100;i++) myvector->push_back(i);
   MyVector *myanothervector = segment.find<MyVector>("MyVector").first;
   std::cout<<"found\n";
   for(int i=0;i<100;i++) std::cout<<(*myanothervector)[i];

   char c;//pause
   std::cin>>c;

   return 0;
}
```

but in client app I can't find a vector, my program freezed when I trying to find a vector in managed_shared_memory(server app already started and still working when I starting client app)

```
//client app
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib> //std::system

#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::interprocess;

typedef allocator<int,managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>  ShmemAllocator;

typedef vector<int, ShmemAllocator> MyVector;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    managed_shared_memory segment(open_only, "MySharedMemory");
    MyVector *somevector = segment.find<MyVector>("MyVector").first;// my program freezed here
    std::cout<<"found\n";
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++) std::cout<<(*somevector)[i];
    segment.destroy<MyVector>("MyVector");
}
```

Comment: The code is fine. You must be doing something else (racing to construction of the vector, or perhaps running more than one client, racing on the destruction). Also, make sure both server and client use *the same compiler flags and (library) versions*